# python2 pandas: how to merge a part of another dataframe to a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df1) as following:

```
       datetime     m  d    1d    2d   3d
       2014-01-01   1  1     2     2   3
       2014-01-02   1  2     3     4   3
       2014-01-03   1  3     1     2   3
       ...........
       2014-12-01  12  1      2     2   3
       2014-12-31  12  31     2     2   3
```

Also I have another dataframe(df2) as following:

```
       datetime     m  d       
       2015-01-02   1  2     
       2015-01-03   1  3     
       ...........
       2015-12-01  12  1      
       2015-12-31  12  31
```

I want to merge the 1d 2d 3d columns value of df1 to df2.
There are two conditions:
    (1) only m and d are the same in both df1 and df2 can merge. 
    (2) if the index of df2  index % 30 ==0 don't merge, the value of 1d 2d 3d of these index can be Nan.

```
I mean I want the new dataframe of df2 like as following:

       datetime     m  d    1d    2d   3d
       2015-01-02   1  2   Nan     Nan   Nan
       2015-01-03   1  3     1     2   3
       ...........
       2015-12-01  12  1      2     2   3
       2015-12-31  12  31     2     2   3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need add `NaN`s by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join:

```
np.random.seed(10)
N = 365
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=N)
df_tr_2014 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 3)), index=rng).reset_index()
df_tr_2014.columns = ['datetime','7d','15d','20d']
df_tr_2014.insert(1,'month', df_tr_2014['datetime'].dt.month)
df_tr_2014.insert(2,'day_m', df_tr_2014['datetime'].dt.day)
#print (df_tr_2014.head())

N = 366
rng = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=N)
df_te = pd.DataFrame(index=rng)
df_te['month'] = df_te.index.month
df_te['day_m'] = df_te.index.day
df_te = df_te.reset_index()
#print (df_te.tail())
df2 = df_te.copy()
df1 = df_tr_2014.copy()
```

---

```
df1 = df1.set_index('datetime')
df1.index += pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

#correct 29 February
y = df1.index[0].year
df1 = df1.reindex(pd.date_range(pd.datetime(y,1,1), pd.datetime(y,12,31)))
idx = df1.index[(df1.index.month == 2) & (df1.index.day == 29)]

df1.loc[idx, :] = df1.loc[idx - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'), :].values
df1.loc[idx, 'day_m'] = idx.day
df1[['month','day_m']] = df1[['month','day_m']].astype(int)

df1[['7d','15d', '20d']] = df1[['7d','15d', '20d']].astype(float)

df1.loc[np.arange(len(df1.index))  % 30 == 0, ['7d','15d','20d']] = 0
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1.iloc[57:62])
        index  month  day_m   7d  15d  20d
57 2016-02-27      2     27  2.0  0.0  1.0
58 2016-02-28      2     28  2.0  3.0  5.0
59 2016-02-29      2     29  2.0  3.0  5.0
60 2016-03-01      3      1  0.0  0.0  0.0
61 2016-03-02      3      2  7.0  6.0  9.0
```

Comment: thanks, how about the leap year, if there is 29 in Feb 2016, there is no 29 in Feb 2015. If there is no 29 in Feb 2015. the 28 and 29 in Feb 2016 are the same

Comment: Hmmm, so you need 30 for each month without february (28,29)? Or need nans for last day of each month?(28,29,30,31)?

Comment: thanks, I mean the year  2016 is leap year , the February have 29, but there is no Feb 29 in 2015. In this case, if there is no 29 in the last year, the data of 29 Feb is the same as data of 28 Feb.

Comment: OK, sorry I forget for your comment.  January has 31 days, do you need select 30 day for it also? February understand. March is too 31... So need select 30 also? thanks.

Comment: thanks for your kind comments.  I mean consider the leap year(just consider Feb). For example 2016 is a leap year, if we want to get the data of a year ago of Feb 29 2016, namely Feb 29 of 2015. But there is no data for Feb 29 of 2015 since it is not a leap year. In this case, the data of  a year ago of Feb 29 ,2016 is same with Feb 28 ,2016.

Comment: thanks, I have solved by f_tr2.index[i]- pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1) which you have answered before. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for comment. My main problem is I dont understand it, why is necessary substract one year and one day? Can you explain it?

Comment: thanks I haven't explained in detail.  But after you have checked my code in answer(I will post my answer), you will understand it.

Comment: Also maybe for your code is necessary use larger dataframe, be free use my data sample and change it if necessary.

Comment: thanks，my code take more time . Could you optimalize it

Comment: But there are no 30 days what is in question. Can you explain it more?

Comment: I have uploaded my new answers about this question, but it take a lot of more, if possible, you can optimize it since I used the loop

Comment: Can you test if sample data can be used for your solution - I add it to your answer.

Comment: hi @jezrael, there is question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946555/python2-7-dataframe-date-format-y-m-d-doesnt-work

Comment: hi @jezrael, there is question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564867/python-2-7-shift-a-dataframe-by-day-and-a-column-value           thanks!

Comment: Do you need `NaN`s? `df = df.shift(1, freq='D')` does not work?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just remove the rows in `df1` that don't match `(m, d)` pairs in `df2`?

```
df_new = df2.drop(df2[(not ((df2.m == df1.m) & (df2.n == df1.n)).any()) or (df2.index % 30 == 0)].index)
```

Or something along those lines.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression) to a related answer.

I'm not enormously familiar with Pandas and have not tested the above example.

Comment: thanks for your comments, how about condition2 : if the index of df2 index % 30 ==0, we don't merge it

Answer (score 0):

df_te is  df2
df_tr_2014 is  df1
7d 15d  20 is 1d 2d 3d respectively in question. size_df_te is the length of df_te, month and day_m are m, d in df2

```
df_te['7d'] = 0
df_te['15d'] = 0
df_te['20d'] = 0
mj = 0
dj = 0
for i in range(size_df_te):
    if i%30 != 0:
        m = df_te.loc[i,'month']
        d = df_te.loc[i,'day_m']
        if (m== 2) & (d == 29):
            m = 2
            d = 28
        dk_7 = df_tr_2014.loc[(df_tr_2014['month']==m) & (df_tr_2014['day_m']==d)]['7d']
        dk_15 = df_tr_2014.loc[(df_tr_2014['month']==m) & (df_tr_2014['day_m']==d)]['15d']
        dk_20 = df_tr_2014.loc[(df_tr_2014['month']==m) & (df_tr_2014['day_m']==d)]['20d']
        df_te.loc[i,'7d'] = float(dk_7)
        df_te.loc[i,'15d'] = float(dk_15)
        df_te.loc[i,'20d'] = float(dk_20)
```

EDIT:

Sample data:

```
np.random.seed(10)
N = 365
rng = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=N)
df_tr_2014 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 3)), index=rng).reset_index()
df_tr_2014.columns = ['datetime','7d','15d','20d']
df_tr_2014.insert(1,'month', df_tr_2014['datetime'].dt.month)
df_tr_2014.insert(2,'day_m', df_tr_2014['datetime'].dt.day)
#print (df_tr_2014.head())

N = 365
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=N)
df_te = pd.DataFrame(index=rng)
df_te['month'] = df_te.index.month
df_te['day_m'] = df_te.index.day
df_te = df_te.reset_index()
#print (df_te.head())
```