# python2.7: dataframe date_format="%Y-%m-%d" doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe

I want the dataframe as following, saved as csv file, and datetime index format is 
"%Y-%m-%d".

```
    date       price_am   price_pm
2017-06-01       E      E
2017-06-02       D      E
2017-06-03       C       D
```

I used the following code, and it doesn't work:

```
df.to_csv('move.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

But when I opened saved cvs file, the datetime format is shown as following:

```
     date         price_am    price_pm
    2017/6/1         E      E
    2017/6/2         D      E
    2017/6/3         C       D
```

How to change datatime format index in the csv file. Thanks!

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2557 entries, 2011-01-01 to 2017-12-31
Data columns (total 2 columns):
price_am    2527 non-null object
price_pm    2526 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 59.9+ KB
```

Comment: Is the date column a string? If so, you need to make it a datetime column first: df['date'] = p.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m%d')

Comment: thanks, it is datetime format not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you verify data in Excel - original dates are changed.

Try some text editor like `Notepad++` - `csv` file data are correct.

If use default options:

```
print (df.head().to_csv())
date,price_am,price_pm
2017-06-01,E,E
2017-06-02,D,E
2017-06-03,C,D
```

Comment: thanks! I think it is: df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'). I used it, it is also doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure if understand - `%Y-%m-%d'` is default format, right?

Comment: hi, I want to datetime index to be this format: %Y-%m-%d". like 2017-06-01 in the csv file, but my csv file just showed the format 2017/6/1  .

Comment: It is really interesting. How do you check csv? by some text editor like notepad ++ ? Because if write datetimeindex without formatters, it should work nice.

Comment: my code:df_move_all.index = df_move_all.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_move_all.index.name = 'date'

Comment: when I print the df in the ipynb: it is ok: price_am price_pm
date  
2011-01-01 NaN NaN
2011-01-02 NaN NaN
2011-01-03 NaN NaN
2011-01-04 E E
2011-01-05 E E

Comment: I double clicked the csv file to open it

Comment: And file is opened in excel?

Comment: And there is problem. excel convert dates. try open in notepad file and data are correct.

Comment: you are right, I confirmed it. It is interesting. thanks!

Comment: hi there is issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670596/python-2-7-pandas-the-previous-4-rows-value-of-a-column-are-value-of-new-column

Comment: Hi @ jezrael  there is another question, could you give me your hand!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431221/python2-7-change-difference-for-a-column-value-of-dataframe

Comment: Thank you, I add answer. Do you want divide by 10 all values of b >= 100 ?