# python2.7: change difference for a column value of dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df) like as following(just example), there are maybe 10 or more dataframes:

```
     date              a       b
  0     2010-01-01     12      15
  1     2010-01-02     13      20
  2     2010-01-03     14      23
  3     2010-01-04     15      24
  4     2010-01-05     16      25
  5     2010-01-08     17      15
  6     2010-01-09     180     160
  ................................
  1000     2013-01-05     310     320
```

I want to calculate the change percentage of b column value in the dataframe.
But there is a exception that when the date is '2010-01-09' (just a example), and calculate the change percentage of b '2010-01-09' , the value of b in'2010-01-08' should be 10 times, just this time, other dates should use the original value, I mean no 10 times. In generally, I calculate the change percent by the following code:

```
df['b_diff'] = df2['b']/(df2['b'].shift() -1
```

But when the date is: '2010-01-09'.
    I think the code should be:

```
 df['b_diff'] = df2['b']/10*(df2['b'].shift()) -1
```

Could you tell me how to process with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html), but first divide value of `b` by condition:

```
dates = ['2010-01-09','2011-01-09']
m = df2['date'].isin(dates)
df2.loc[m, 'b'] =  df2['b'] / 10

df2['b_diff'] = df2['b'].pct_change()
print (df2)
        date    a     b    b_diff
0 2010-01-01   12  15.0       NaN
1 2010-01-02   13  20.0  0.333333
2 2010-01-03   14  23.0  0.150000
3 2010-01-04   15  24.0  0.043478
4 2010-01-05   16  25.0  0.041667
5 2010-01-08   17  15.0 -0.400000
6 2010-01-09  180  16.0  0.066667
```

Alternative solution:

```
dates = ['2010-01-09','2011-01-09']
m = df2['date'].isin(dates)

df2['b'] = df2['b'].mask(m, df2['b'] / 10)
df2['b_diff'] = df2['b'].pct_change()
print (df2)
        date    a     b    b_diff
0 2010-01-01   12  15.0       NaN
1 2010-01-02   13  20.0  0.333333
2 2010-01-03   14  23.0  0.150000
3 2010-01-04   15  24.0  0.043478
4 2010-01-05   16  25.0  0.041667
5 2010-01-08   17  15.0 -0.400000
6 2010-01-09  180  16.0  0.066667
```

Comment: thanks, I want to change the value based on dates, not based on the value, there are maybe not a dates should be changed. For example there are two times should be changed: '2010-01-09'  and 2011-01-09. Please just consider the work day.

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, I just want to change temporarily  the value of  b when the date is  '2010-01-08', when we want to get the change percentage of  b in date '2010-01-09'.  I mean when get the change of percentage of  b in date '2010-01-10' use the original value of b in date '2010-01-09'. The same as date '2010-01-08'

Comment: I am sorry for poor explanation

Comment: No problem. Do you need `df2['b_diff'] = np.where(m, df2['b']/ 10 /(df2['b'].shift())-1, df2['b'] /(df2['b'].shift()) -1)` ? It is same as my solution.

Comment: I have checked , and it is right, thanks, you can edit your answer using np.where or add it

Comment: thanks for your kind answer @jezrael , there is another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503965/python-pandas-combine-two-dataframes-by-date-index-and-a-common-column-value