# Python 2.7: shift a dataframe by day and a column value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named  df1 as following:

df1:

```
               a   b    id
2010-01-01     2   3    21
2010-01-01     2   4    22
2010-01-01     3   5    23
2010-01-01     4   6    24
2010-01-02     1   4    21
2010-01-02     2   5    22
2010-01-02     3   6    23
2010-01-02     4   7    24
2010-01-03     1   8    21
2010-01-03     2   9    22
2010-01-03     3   10    23
2010-01-03     4   11   24
...........................
```

I want to shift the value of a, b and id, the i rows value become the i+1 rows value. As you can see the df1, the same date have several rows, and the id is different. I want to shift the df1, I mean the 2010-01-02 value to be the 2010-01-03 value based on the id(I mean that 2010-01-02 value of id 21, to be the  2010-01-03 value of id 21). Thanks!

My desired answer:

```
                a   b    id
2010-01-01     Nan   Nan    Nan
2010-01-01     Nan   Nan    Nan
2010-01-01     Nan   Nan    Nan
2010-01-01     Nan   Nan    Nan
2010-01-02     2   3    21
2010-01-02     2   4    22
2010-01-02     3   5    23
2010-01-02     4   6    24
2010-01-03     1   4    21
2010-01-03     2   5    22
2010-01-03     3   6    23
2010-01-03     4   7    24
...........................
```

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: are the number of rows and the set of id values for each date the same? What I am asking is for 2010-01-01 we have four rows and we also have four rows for 2010-01-02. Is this the case for the entire data? Do all dates have four rows? Also, in this example the set of id values are 21 to 24. Is this consistent throughout the data?

Comment: thanks for your comments! there number of rows, id are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all groups are same length (in sample 4) and `DatetimeIndex` is sorted:

```
df2 = df.shift((df.index == df.index[0]).sum())
print (df2)
              a    b    id
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-02  2.0  3.0  21.0
2010-01-02  2.0  4.0  22.0
2010-01-02  3.0  5.0  23.0
2010-01-02  4.0  6.0  24.0
2010-01-03  1.0  4.0  21.0
2010-01-03  2.0  5.0  22.0
2010-01-03  3.0  6.0  23.0
2010-01-03  4.0  7.0  24.0
```

But if need shift values of index by one day:

```
df3 = df.shift(1, freq='D')
print (df3)
            a   b  id
2010-01-02  2   3  21
2010-01-02  2   4  22
2010-01-02  3   5  23
2010-01-02  4   6  24
2010-01-03  1   4  21
2010-01-03  2   5  22
2010-01-03  3   6  23
2010-01-03  4   7  24
2010-01-04  1   8  21
2010-01-04  2   9  22
2010-01-04  3  10  23
2010-01-04  4  11  24
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the way is with the help of shape if the dates are sorted i.e

```
df.shift(df.loc[df.index[0]].shape[0])
# Or len 
df.shift(len(df.loc[df.index[0]]))
```

Output :

```
              a    b    id
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN
2010-01-02  2.0  3.0  21.0
2010-01-02  2.0  4.0  22.0
2010-01-02  3.0  5.0  23.0
2010-01-02  4.0  6.0  24.0
2010-01-03  1.0  4.0  21.0
2010-01-03  2.0  5.0  22.0
2010-01-03  3.0  6.0  23.0
2010-01-03  4.0  7.0  24.0
```